# Hide <s:param> from the url

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

In my jsp page, there is link as follows.

```
<s:url var="editReqDetails" action="editReqDetails">
   <s:param name="siteID" value="siteId"/>
</s:url>
```

when I click on that link, browser URL is

> `http://`localhost:7101/legal/editReqDetails?**siteID=99**

like above.(The parameter shows in the URL.)

I want to know how to hide above highlighted part(the parameter) from the url.

Comment: Well if the request is a get request you **can't** hide that and expect the same result

Comment: I did not set any get or post action to the URL .(I am using struts 2 framework.)

Comment: @lpushpe: you are passing a parameter as query string and there is no way you can hide it.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Then how do I pass that parameter through link from struts 2.

Comment: You can see [this][1] post. I hope you are looking for the same.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/962452

Comment: Actually I want know, How to pass a parameter through link, without shows in url , **using Struts 2**

Comment: You pass a param through a url by passing a param through a url. At best you could do a redirect, a post via ajax, etc. All could be viewed. And a link as shown *is* a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript you could do this

```
<s:a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='%{editReqDetails}'">Edit Details</s:a>
```

This way you "hide" the url from the user. Though I'm not sure what the big problem is. If the user is malicious he can easily look in the source and get the values.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use this. You pass parameter with http GET method that is default used in s:url tag and you want to get http POST method behavior. See [the usage of struts url](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/URL.html) and choose one http GET or POST method.

Comment: Did u suggest to use **includeParams="none"** ?
I try it but still parameters include in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<form id="edit-form" action="editReqDetails" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="siteID" value="siteId" />
</form>
```

Then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#your-link").click(function(e) {
            $("#edit-form").submit();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```